# Closed Form for $\sum\limits_{n=-2a}^\infty(n+a){2a\choose-n}^4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, closed-form

> Do either $~S_4^+(a)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+a){2a\choose n}^4~$ or $~S_4^-(a)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-2a}^\infty(n+a){2a\choose-n}^4~$ possess a meaningful closed form expression in terms of the general parameter *a* ?

[Ramanujan](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503975) provided the following [result](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/285746) : $~S_4^-\Big(-\tfrac18\Big)~=~\dfrac1{\bigg[\Big(-\tfrac14\Big){\large!}\bigg]^2~\sqrt{8\pi}}~,~$ which would point to a possible closed form expression in terms of $~(2a)!~$ and/or $~(4a)!~$

---

For lesser values of the exponent, we have [Dixon's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity) :

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n{2a\choose n}^3 ~=~ \sum_{n=-2a}^\infty(-1)^n{2a\choose-n}^3 ~=~ \cos(a\pi)~{3a\choose a,a},$$

and [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) :

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n{2a\choose n}^2 ~=~ \sum_{n=-2a}^\infty(-1)^n{2a\choose-n}^2 ~=~ \cos(a\pi)~{2a\choose a},$$
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a\choose n}^2 ~=~ \sum_{n=-a}^\infty{a\choose-n}^2 ~=~ {2a\choose a},$$

as well as the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) :

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a\choose n}^1x^n ~=~ (1+x)^a,\qquad\sum_{n=-a}^\infty{a\choose-n}^1x^n ~=~ \Big(1+\tfrac1x\Big)^a.$$

Comment: First of all, good to see you back here ! I suppose that you do not want hypergeometric functions. Right ? Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Same here. :-) And no, since the latter are simply an exercise in mathematical taxonomy, so to say.

Comment: I was sure of that.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347906/closed-form-for-sum-limits-n-2a-inftyna2a-choose-n4-a-not-in-mathbb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I am posting this answer, so as to remove this question from the ever-growing [Unanswered Queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered), where, thanks to the substantial contribution of the mathematical community at [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/347906), it no longer belongs.*

$$S_4^-(a)~=~S_3^-(a)\cdot{4a\choose2a}~=~-\frac{\sin(2a\pi)}{2\pi}\cdot{4a\choose2a}$$

See [Dougall's very well-poised summation formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.4#E9); also, notice that both sides satisfy the same recursion formula.

Answer (score 3):

**When $2a$ is a non-negative integer:**
$$S=\sum_{n=-2a}^{\infty} (n+a) {2a \choose -n}^4= \sum_{n=0}^{2a}(-n+a) {2a \choose n}^4=\sum_{n=0}^{2a}~(-(2a-n)+a)~{2a\choose n}^4$$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^{2a} (n-a) {2a \choose n}^4~ =-S.$$ So $$S=-S \implies S=0$$.Here we have used : ${n \choose-k}= 0~$ if $k\in I^+$, $\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k) =\sum_{k=0}^n f(n-k)$, and ${n \choose k}={n \choose n-k}$

Comment: For some mysterious reason, this answer seems to assume that the two parameters are integers. As can be clearly inferred from the question's second paragraph, this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @Lucian OK, I have reduced ny claim now in the edit.

Comment: He solved a case he could handle.