# The closed-form of $1-5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k+9\left(\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}\right)^k-13\left(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{2\cdot4\cdot6}\right)^k+\dots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, gamma-function, pi

(*A related [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2507041/4781) by P. Singh*.) First define,

$$F_k = 1-5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k+9\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\right)^k-13\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\right)^k+17\left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8}\right)^k-\cdots$$

Or more concisely,

$$F_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\, (-1)^n\,(4n+1) \left(\frac{\Gamma\big(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\;\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big)}\right)^k$$

The gamma quotient is also,

$$ \frac{\Gamma\big(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\;\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big)} = \frac1{2^{2n}}\frac{(2n)!}{\,n!^2}$$

Then we have the nice closed-forms,

\begin{align}
F_1 &= 0\\[4pt]
F_2 &= \dfrac{2\sqrt2\,\Gamma\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big)}{\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac{1}{4}\big)}\\[4pt]
F_3 &= \dfrac{2}{\Gamma^2\big(\tfrac{1}{2}\big)}=\dfrac{2}{\pi} \\[4pt]
F_4 &= \; \color{red}{??}\\[4pt]
F_5 &= \dfrac{2}{\Gamma^4\big(\tfrac{3}{4}\big)}
\end{align}

I found $F_2$ empirically. The closed-form of $F_3=\large\frac{2}{\pi}$ was included by Ramanujan in his letter to Hardy, and $F_5$ is also by him. (I presume a version of $F_2$ may be in his Notebooks.)

---

Alternatively, while the $F_k$ are clearly a sum of two generalized hypergeometric functions $_pF_q$, we learn from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746826/4781) that they can also be expressed as just **one** $_pF_q$,

\begin{align}
F_1 &= \,_2F_1\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac54;\tfrac14;-1\big)\\[4pt]
F_2 &= \,_3F_2\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac54;\tfrac14,1;-1\big)\\[4pt]
F_3 &= \,_4F_3\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac54;\tfrac14,1,1;-1\big)\\[4pt]
F_4 &= \,_5F_4\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac54;\tfrac14,1,1,1;-1\big)= \; \color{red}{??}\\[4pt]
F_5 &= \,_6F_5\big(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac54;\tfrac14,1,1,1,1;-1\big)
\end{align}

and so on.

---

**Question**: What is the closed-form of $F_4,\,F_6$ and others, if any?

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the hypergeometic closed form [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28%28-1%29%5En+%281+%2B+4+n%29+Γ%281%2F2+%2B+n%29%5E4%29%2F%28π%5E2+Γ%281+%2B+n%29%5E4%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D)?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Wolfram can actually reduce $F_5$, but I don't know why it has trouble with $F_4$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Once again, an interesting question! Do you have a numerical expansion of $F_4$? Might be worth checking out such a representation with an inverse symbolic calculator

Comment: @MaxMuller Thanks. This [WA command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%28HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%2C+1%2F2%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%2C+1%7D%2C+-1%5D+-+%28HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B3%2F2%2C+3%2F2%2C+3%2F2%2C+3%2F2%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+2%2C+2%7D%2C+-1%5D%29%2F4%29%2C100%5D) should give it to 100 digits, It starts as 0.79443356000157023489670877173541913133327484204150... I assumed it was a product of gamma functions and some radicals, but no hits on _Mathematica's_ integer relations so far.

Comment: If the terms were not alternating in sign we can get the value of $F_4$ using Dougall formula: see https://mathoverflow.net/a/292294/15540

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I have a feeling it may involve a _sum_ and not just a product of gamma functions. In this [2020 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746826/4781) by Infiniticism, it is discussed how $F_5$ in fact is a consequence of the Dougall formula.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It seems one person down-voted Tomita's two [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4840152/4781) to my question in rapid succession, apparently for no good reason. Can you verify if indeed it was just one person?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: voting is anonymous to moderators in the sense that they don't have information on who voted on a specific post. However the timings of the down votes does suggest that it was probably some form of targeted voting. Usually votes in quick succession are reversed by the system. But in any case the user Tomita can raise a flag for targeted voting.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see. It is sad the community is tainted by a few bad apples. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Although not quite the same, we have

$$\int_0^1K^2dk=\frac{\pi^4}{32}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^6\left(\frac{1+4n}{2^{12n}}\right)$$

$$\int_0^1kK^4dk=\frac{3\pi^6}{256}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^8\left(\frac{1+4n}{2^{16n}}\right)$$